# Adding texture to json not loading

Tags: javascript, json, opengl-es, webgl, texture-mapping

I am trying to add texture to an jsonloaded object, which is not loading for some reason.

**javascript**

```
// Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
loader.load(jsonPath, function (geometry, materials ) {
    skateboardBase = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    scene.add(skateboardBase);
});
```

if I remove the materials part, things work fine without texture

**json**

```
"materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "SVGMat.001",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.3294117738218869, 0.6243137452649137, 0.3607843214390325],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.3294117738218869, 0.6243137452649137, 0.3607843214390325],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                "illumination" : 2,
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false,
                "mapDiffuse" : "../textures/dash.jpg",
        "shading" : "Lambert"
    }],
"vertices" : [1.32997,1.125,-0.870963,1.34966,1.125, ... ],
"uvs" : [],
"faces" : [34,124,126,125,0,...],
```

**Error**

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know threejs very well, but at first glance you have an empty `uvs` array. Without textures I guess threejs just doesn't use this array at all, there's no need. When you add a material with a texture suddenly it tries to use the array, which is empty. Hence GL gives the  out of bounds error (rather nice of it - desktop GL would just crash :) ) where I'd assume attribute 2 is the uv array.

To fix this, populate `uvs` (Or don't provide them and write a shader to generate them implicitly).

GL can't use separate indices for vertex attributes. The number of UVs must match the number of vertices exactly. Also, the indices in the `faces` array cannot reference vertices that don't exist.

Comment: @YellowandRed UVs are [texture coordinates](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=texture+coordinates), 2D u/v coordinates to map each vertex to a position in the texture.